# Joining two tables in JPA when the entities does not have relation mapping between them

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a User entity and a Pet entity. There are no @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or other between the User and the Pet. The reason is that each user may have thousands of pets (at least in this example). Since I don't want to eager load it (too slow) and I don't want to lazy load (cause lazy initialization exception...and I don't want to use open in view filter) I have created methods in the user repository that have a name like this (the reason is that I want to have the opportunity to return only subsets of the relational properties. I don't want all the pets of a user:

`getPetsForUser(final User user){...}`. The examples of joins I have seen in JPA obviously uses the relational property on the entities it seems. How do I do this in JPA?

In SQL I would just use the foreign key...

Answer (score 2):

JPQL only works on mapped entity and mapped relationships.
One way is to use native SQL query and manage result as [`List<Object[]>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959070/iterate-listobject-from-join-query-using-jpa-play).
Else you can unwrap `EntityManager` to obtain a Hibernate `Session` and mappign result with `SQLQuery.setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Pet.class))`.
For example:

```
List<Pet> getPetsForUser(final User user) {
    Session s = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    List<Pet> pets = s.createSQLQuery("select * from PETS p inner join USERS u on (p.user_id = u.id) where u.id = :id").setParameter("id",user.getUserID()).setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Pet.class)).list();
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but still relevant. The only thing that is missing from this answer is you need to chain at the end of the `List<Pet> pets...` is `.list()`, otherwise you will get an error saying: `org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl cannot be cast to java.util.List`. Other than that this is really the best answer for joining non related tables and returning them as some sort of object.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to explicitly use the foreign key, probably by extracting it from the `User` object (`User.getId()`, I presume) and then using it as a raw `long` or equivalent field on the `Pet`--with no foreign-key integrity, cascades, or query-based joins.

You might be better off reexamining why getting lazy-loading working is such a bad thing, and if JPA is the right approach.